# Stackoverflow on premise solution or other Q&A/ Support forum site

Tags: forum, stack-exchange, knowledge-organization, knowledge-base

I know StackOverflow is only public, but I'm looking for free open source software like StackOverflow.

The posts I found are really old ones or paid and charge too much for me like AnserHub and AnserBase
I'm looking for something like http://www.mkyong.com/featured/top-5-open-source-qa-systems/ (These projects are old and not maintained).

I tried PhpBB but it is far different from StackOverflow.

Do you have a good Q&A or forum solution?

The features I would appreciate:

1. Subscribe to tags by getting emails.
2. Admin console.
3. Add Images/ attach files.
4. Open source.
5. Large development community.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. What features do you need? What would you rather not like to have?

Comment: The solutions there is out dated, or not on premise

Comment: @MarkT To make your case, what I would do is make a note at the top of your question, stating that you are aware of that question and maybe give a brief explanation as to why you asked a new one.

Comment: And maybe in here there are also candidates: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones